# test for free drive letter to map

Tags: powershell

I am mapping and un-mapping drives in my script.  I ran into a need to determine if a drive letter is already mapped which is easy with `test-path`.

The problem is how do I go for the next available drive letter if there is one?

```
New-PSDrive -Name "S" -Root "\\<Name>\GYBWatch" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Persist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
[char[]] $taken = (Get-PSDrive -Name [A-Z]).Name
$nextAvailable = ([char[]] (65..90)).Where({ $_ -notin $taken }, 'First')[0]

if (-not $nextAvailable) { throw "No drive letters available." }
```

- `(Get-PSDrive -Name [A-Z])` uses a [wildcard expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) to get information about all currently defined single-letter-name drives.

  - `.Name` uses [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) to return an array of the names of all these drives, i.e. the taken letters as strings.
  - The `[char[]]` type constraint applied to variable `$taken` converts the array of single-letter strings to an array of `[char]` instances.
- `[char[]] (65..90)` programmatically creates the array of (English) uppercase letters, `'A', 'B', ..., 'Z'`, using `..`, the [range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#range-operator-). In *PowerShell (Core) 7+* you can use character endpoints directly: `'A'..'Z'`. Note that PowerShell is case-*insensitive* in general, so the case of these letters is irrelevant.
- The [`.Where()` array method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where) iterates over each letter and returns the first letter (`'First'`) that satisfies the condition:

  - `$_ -notin $taken` returns `$true` if the input letter at hand (`$_`) is *not* an element of ([`-notin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-in-and--notin)) the `$taken` array, i.e. it returns `$true` if the letter isn't currently taken.
  - Note that `[0]` is applied to the `.Where()` call so as to ensure that the (at most) one and only result is treated as a *scalar*, which is necessary, because the `.Where()` and `.ForEach()` methods *always* return a *collection*. That said, in PowerShell the distinction between a scalar and a collection with a single element often doesn't matter.

Note: The above starts looking for available drive letters with letter `A` (drive `A:`).
To start looking from a *different* letter - say `E` - do the following:

- Adjust the starting character in the letter-array-creation operation, `..`

  ```sh
  [char[]] (69..90) # 'E', 'F', ..., 'Z'
  ```

  - `69`, i.e. the decimal form of the Unicode code point of the uppercase `E` letter, was obtained with `[int] [char] 'E'`
  - Again, in *PowerShell (Core) 7+* you could simply use `'E'..'Z'`
- As an *optional optimization* you could additionally adjust the wildcard pattern in the `Get-PSDrive` call:

  ```sh
  (Get-PSDrive -Name [E-Z]).Name
  ```

---

An **alternative solution** that **avoids looping and linear searches in arrays**:

- **Surprisingly, however, it is *slower*** than the solution above, perhaps due to overhead of exception handling; in practice, both solutions will likely perform acceptably.
- It takes advantage of the fact that you can pass *multiple* drive letters (names) to the `-Name` parameter; non-existent names trigger a non-terminating error that can be escalated to a terminating one with `-ErrorAction Stop`, which can then be trapped with [`try { ... } catch { ... }`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally).
- The offending name - the nonexistent drive letter - is reported in the error record's `.TargetObject` property (reported via the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) in the `catch` block, as an [`[ErrorRecord]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord) instance).

```sh
$nextAvailable =
  try {
    $null = Get-PSDrive -ErrorAction Stop -Name ([char[]] (65..90))
  } catch {
    $_.TargetObject
  }

if (-not $nextAvailable) { throw "No drive letters available." }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#quick and dirty 
#create Alphabet

   $alphabet = @()  
   for ([byte]$c = [char]'A'; $c -le [char]'Z'; $c++){  
       $alphabet += [char]$c  
   }  
   [String]::Join(", ", $alphabet)

#get all Letter which are not in use

   $alphabet | where { (Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | select -ExpandProperty Name) -notcontains $_  }
```

Comment: Nice, though note that you'll need to append `| Select-Object -First 1` in order to output just the _first_ available letter. A few tips: You can create the character array more succinctly and more efficiently via `..`, the [range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#range-operator-), as follows: `[char[]] (65..90)`, or - more conveniently in _PowerShell (Core) 7+_ - `'A'..'Z'`. (In general, it's [best to avoid `+=` to iteratively build arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/45375)).

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.